# PHP increment statement according to value in database

Tags: php

I have created a PHP form with values that are inserted in the database. Fields dropdown boxes that are passed to the database after submit. According to what the user chooses in the dropdown box, score increases.

It contains age (dropdown box, >20 <20), degree (high school, university), etc.

What I want to build,is a function to add score values according to the choice of the dropdown box. Make specific column values a variable which adds scores points.

Every time someone inserts a specific choice, it should  get a different amount of points.

Pseudocode, for score:

```
i = 0.
If dropdown.age>20 (choice 1), 5 points, i= i +5. 
If dropdown.age<20, 10 points, i= i +10
If dropdownchoicebox.education = high school, 5 points, if university, 10 points.
```

Same for database

```
If age-row.value>20, i +5 else i+10
if education-row.value = highschool, i= i+5 else i + 10
```

And it should continue giving "score points", according to each specific choice in every field.

The code so far shows the database values. Each insert is in a different row until it runs out rows. For instance, age would be row 4, education row 5, etc.

```
   <?php

// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all records from the user profile table.
// Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName(array(age, education, FieldName, FieldValue)));
$query->from($db->quoteName('table'));


// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadRow();
print_r($row);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
?>
```

Result: array value

```
Array ( [0] => over 20 [1] => highschool [2] => result 2[3] => result3
```

Names of rows: [0] = age, [1] = education.

What I want to do:

```
Button onclick: calculate points

function calculate points
//i for score

i=0
As 0 = over 20, i=0+5 = 5
as 1 = highschool i= 5+5 = 10
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking! Do you want to display the score (i) ?

Comment: Yes. Updating question.

Comment: I want to help but I am not sure what the question or problem is still

Comment: What I want to do, is add points according to the choice of dropdown box. Updating further.